# how to run a function with parameters

Tags: javascript, function, optional-parameters

I have a function that simply validates forms (for old browsers). The function works just fine except that I have to pass the parameters every time I call this function, where in fact I already specified the default parameters in 'config'.

So by logic, If I called the function as: `validateMe();` it should run as `validateMe({requiredClass: '.required', verifiedClass: 'invalid'});`

but unfortunately calling the function without parameters doesn't work correctly ( in my case the form triggers the submission event) (it doesn't reach `return false`).

so what is missing in the code to run the function with the default settings??

```
function validateMe(vform, settings) {

    var vform,      //form name or id
        config = {
            'requiredClass': '.required', 
            'verifiedClass': 'invalid'
        };
    if (settings) {
        $.extend(config, settings);
    }

    $(vform).on('submit', function(){

        var inputs =  $(this).find(config.requiredClass), 
            required = [];
        for (i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

            if (inputs[i] != null) {
                if ($(inputs[i]).val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') == '') {
                    required.push($(inputs[i]).index());
                }
            }
        }

        if (required.length > 0) {
            $(this).find('input').removeClass(config.verifiedClass);
            for(n=0;n<required.length;n++) {
                $(inputs[n]).addClass(config.verifiedClass);
            }
            return false;   
        }

    });
}
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateMe(vform, settings) {
this.vform = vform || 'default',
this.setting = 'whatever',
this.private = ''
}
var newInstance = new validateMe();
```

now you have an instance of it, so you can define it as you go.

Comment: no it doesn't, it's in the function definition?  this is basic decorator pattern, maybe you are thinking of $(this)

Comment: So? What is next? The alert in jsfiddle returns back 'default'.. What does this mean?

Comment: well, i hate to tell you but, that's not how you use it.
u say var newInstance = new validateMe();
then try it, and you will get undefined.

Comment: the real problem is this guy above want to use a function like an object without knowing it ;)